# Basic arboricity example

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

I'm having some trouble proving two interesting properties of arboricity of a graph. Arboricity is defined as the minimal number of forests into which a graph can be divided, and it can also be expressed by a formula via the Nasch-Williams theorem. However, I'd like to strictly restrict to the definition without using the Nash-Williams theorem.

My first goal is to prove an $n$-vertex complete graph $G$ has an arboricity of $\frac{n}{2}$ (ofcourse without using Nash-Williams). I tried the following: I know each forest can hold up to $n-1$ edges. The total amount of edges in $G$ is $\frac{n\cdot\left( n -1 \right)}{2}$. Hence the arboricity of $G$ cannot be lower then $\frac{n}{2}$.

But how do I prove it cannot be larger?

A different approach to this that I have tried is without searching for upper and lower bound, but simply finding such a decomposition. I tried to find a general way to construct such a forest decomposition, but could not find.

Similarly to this, I am also attempting to prove a planar graph has arboricoty $\leq 3$, but I find it even harder then for the complete graph.

Comment: Sorry, I meant planar.

Comment: See [here](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0166218X98000079/1-s2.0-S0166218X98000079-main.pdf?_tid=6b9f0f95-0b0a-4ca4-9caf-738bf9efc4a8&acdnat=1552433719_eb5370c0130cef4b28323edbb7643d05) for a "simple" method to partition a planar graph into three forests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an inductive construction:

Assume you have a decomposition in $n-1$ trees for $K_{2n-2}$. We can build a decomposition of $K_{2n}$ in $n$ trees in the following way: for $i = 1 \ldots n-1$, in the $i-th$ tree:

- The edges between $v_1, \ldots v_{2n-2}$ in the $i$-th tree are the same as in the $K_{2n-2}$ construction.
- $v_{2n-1}$ is connected to $v_{i}$
- $v_{2n}$ is connected to $v_{n-1+i}$

Then let the $n$-th tree be the one formed by connecting $v_{2n-1}$ with $v_n, \ldots v_{2n-2}$, $v_{2n}$ with $v_1, \ldots v_{n-1}$ and connecting $v_{2n-1}$ and $v_{2n}$ together.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you can partition $K_{2n}$ into $n$ paths of length $2n-1$ as follows. Number the vertices $1$ to $2n$. For each $i=1,2,\dots,n$, the $i^{th}$ path is
$$
(i,i+1,i-1,i+2,i-2,i+3,i-3,\dots,i+n-1,i-n+1,i+n)
$$
All addition is modulo $2n$. Each path is a zig zag. When $n=4$, the result is

[image]

To partition $K_{2n+1}$ into $n+1$ trees, perform this construction on the vertices number $1$ through $2n$, then add one more tree consisting of vertex number $2n+1$ connected to every other vertex.

Comment: But this way, you get $\frac{n}{2}$ paths when the amount of vertices is $2n$. Should $i$ be at most $n$? Could you elaborate a bit more why each path will be a forest? (maybe I just need a small clarification to see it)

Comment: Small typo, there are $n$ paths. Each path is a tree, since paths have no cycles. Trees are forests with one component.

Comment: But why does this (disjoint?) partition cover the entire set of edges? For a set of 2 vertices $(v_j , v_{j+k} )$ I want to show that the edge is in (only) one of these paths. In other words, I want to find a pair of vertices in one $i$-th path s.t. the difference in their indices will be $k$. Lets ignore $i$ for a moment. So we have: $(1, 2, 2n-2, 3, 2n-3, 4, 2n-4, ...., n-1, n+3, n-, n+1, n)$. The first difference is $1$, then between $2$ to $2n-1$ it is $2n-3$, then the next difference is $2n-4$ and so on until between $n+1$ and $n$ is 1 again.But we missed differences $2n-2$ and $2n-1$?

Comment: (Can't edit. I meant $i$ doesn't matter for the differences. So for $i=1$ we have $(1, 2, 2n-2, 3, 2n-3, 4, 2n-4, ...., n-1, n+3, n, n+2, n+1)$. And it seems like not all differences are covered.

Comment: @Eric_ Think about it longer and try more examples, like $n=2,3$. You will see it works.